# Tensor product of simple modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, tensor-products, modules

Let $M$ a right simple module and $N$ be a left simple module over a ring $R$. I'm seeking a kind of Schur's lemma, with $\mathrm{Hom}_R (M,N)$ replaced by $M \otimes_R N$. So my questions are:

Can we describe $M \otimes_R N$ explicitly?

In particular, for a fixed $M$, is $N$ such that $M \otimes_R N \neq 0$ unique up to isomorphism? If not, can we classify such $N$'s in a reasonable way?

Comment: If $R$ is an algebra over a field $k$ then 
$$
Hom_k(M\otimes_R N,k) = Hom_R(M,Hom_k(N,k)) = Hom_R(M,N^*),
$$
so, for example if all simple $R$-modules are finite dimensional over $k$ then $M\otimes_R N \ne 0$ iff $M = N^*$.

Comment: If $I_1$ and $I_2$ are two ideals of the ring $R$ then 
$\frac{R}{I_1} \otimes \frac{R}{I_2}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{R}{I_1 + I_2}$ .So if $R$ is commutative then $M \otimes N$ is $0$ or $M$ or $N$.

Comment: @Sasha: Thank you. Actually, my intention was to understand this duality relation in a more general context...

Comment: @AliReza: Right, but for commutative rings simple modules are just one-dimensional vector spaces over fields, so the answer is straightforward. :) In the noncommutative setting the $R/(I_1+I_2)$ description remains valid, but $I_1$ and $I_2$ are now ideals from different sides, and they are not even uniquely defined. Can we still get something useful from this sum of ideals?

Comment: Yes, as abelian groups (or modules over the center of $R$). There is an additive homomorphism $R \to I_1\backslash R/I_2$, which is surjective and its kernel is the sum of $I_1$ and $I_2$ as abelian groups. Beyond that, it's at least as hard as double cosets, which are pretty annoying to work with.

Comment: A trivial observation about this duality, yet somewhat unexpected for me: the dual module doesn't depend on the field used to construct it. At least, under certain finiteness conditions. $\mathrm{Hom}$ cancels the field out, just like $\otimes$ would do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sasha's statement is true for any pair of modules.

The center of $R$ is a commutative ring $S$. Since the endomorphisms of a simple module are a division algebra, whose center is a field, the action of $S$ on every simple module factors through some field, so the action of $R$ of course factors through an algebra over that field.

The kenel of a map to a field is a prime ideal $p$, and the map to the field factors through the residue field $k_p$.

So if we have two finitely-generated modules $M$ and $N$, their annihilators in $S$ are two prime ideals of $S$, $p_1,p_2$. If the ideals are distinct, then $S$ annihilates $M \otimes_R N$ since the action of $S$ factors through $k_{p_1} \otimes_S k_{p_2}=0$. The tensor product is zero because one ideal necessarily contains an element $e$ not in the other. In the residue field that element, since it's not in the ideal, has an inverse. Then $1= 1\otimes 1= e^{-1}e\otimes 1=e^{-1}\otimes e=e^{-1} \otimes 0 =0$.

If they are the same ideal, set $R'= R\otimes_S k_p$. It is now an algebra over a field. Apply Sasha's statement.

Comment: "If the module is finitely-generated then the field is finitely-generated over $S$..."  In what sense do you want $M$ to be finitely generated?  As an $S$-module?

Comment: Yes. If $R$ is reasonable you can get away with making it finitely-generated as an $R$-module but not all rings are reasonable.

Comment: Perhaps you need $S$ to be Noetherian - otherwise I don't see how you show that the center of $\mathrm{End}_R M$ is a finitely generated $S$-module. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: As I suspected, there's a way to fix it so there are no finiteness conditions needed.

Comment: You forgot to invert $S - p$.

Comment: Inverting $S - p$ is part of the definition of the residue field as I understand it.

Comment: That's nice. But why use commutative fields at all? Sasha's tensor-hom adjunction works perfectly for, say, right vector spaces over $k := \mathrm{End}_R N$, so that $(M \otimes_R N)^\ast = \mathrm{Hom}(M, N^\ast)$, where $\ast = \mathrm{Hom}_k(-,k)$. This gives the answer if $N$ (or $M$, by symmetry) is finite-dimensional over its $\mathrm{End}$, which is obviously a weaker condition.

Comment: On the other hand, if $N$ is infinite-dimensional over its $\mathrm{End}$, $N^\ast$ may not be simple at all. One example is the ring of infinite-dimensional matrices with finitely many nonzero entries (+ scalars), acting naturally on an infinite-dimensional vector space $N$. In this case the adjoint module $N^\ast$ is not even semisimple, but it has a simple submodule consisting of "finite" functionals, and the latter has nontrivial tensor product with $N$.

Comment: Do you feel the question has been sufficiently answered by the combination of Sasha's argument, my argument, and that one? Would you like an answer that deals with the case of infinite-dimensional modules?

Answer (score 6):

I would guess the answer in general is hopeless, even for nice (noncommutative) algebras. For example, take $A_q := \mathbb C \langle X^{\pm 1}, Y^{\pm 1}\rangle / (XY=q^2YX)$, the quantum torus. If $q \in \mathbb C^*$ is not a root of unity, this is a simple algebra with trivial center. Let $M = P_k = \mathbb C[x^{\pm 1 }]$ as vector spaces with $1$ mapping to $m_0$ and $p_k$, respectively. Give $M$ and $P_k$ right and left $A_q$-module structures using

$f(x)m\cdot X = f(q^{-2}x) m$ and $f(x)m\cdot Y = xf(x)m$

$X\cdot f(x) p_k = xf(x)p_k$ and $Y\cdot f(x)m = q^{-k}x^k f(q^{-2}x)p_k$.

Claim: All the $P_k$ are non-isomorphic, each vector space $M \otimes_{A_q} P_k$ is 1-dimensional (spanned by $m\otimes p_k$), and if $q \in \mathbb C^*$ is not a root of unity, then $M$ and $P_k$ are simple.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Did you mean $Y \cdot f(x)p_k = q^{-k} x^k f(q^{-2} x) p_k$?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: BTW, for anyone that happens to read this, if there's a minor typo to correct in an answer, is it better to just correct it in the comments so that the question doesn't get bumped to the front page?

Comment: Peter, I think the community standard is to correct the answer. See the meta threads http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/906/minor-andor-repeated-edits/ and http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/394/minor-edits/. 