# A reference on semisimple linear algebra

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, linear-algebra

Is there any literature where the tools familiar from (multi)linear algebra are systematically transferred to the setting of semisimple modules over noncommutative rings?

In fact this question is a vast generalization of [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105339/tensor-product-of-simple-modules), but I chose to post it separately as a reference request...